# How to retrieve the source code of an object?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose a class

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
    def get_entry(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

Create an instance:

```
>>> book = Book('Think Python', 'Allen')
>>> vars(book)
{'title': 'Think Python', 'author': 'Allen'}
```

I go a further step to retrieve the statement of object book.
The output I intent is `{'title': 'Think Python', 'author': 'Allen','get_entry':statements}`

So I import `inspect` to get info of the live object

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(book)
```

Errors report

```
TypeError: <__main__.Book object at 0x10f3a0908> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

However, python documents specify 'Return the text of the source code for an object. The argument may be a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object. The source code is returned as a single string. An OSError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved.'
[29.12. inspect — Inspect live objects — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect%20getsource#inspect.getsource)
What's wrong here?

Comment: You need to pass `getsource` the class itself and not an instance. `inspect.getsource(Book)` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getsource` function works with Classes, not instances of the class. So, you'd have to pass it as follows:

```
inspect.getsource(Book) # Book is the class, defined by 'class Book:'
```

rather than:

```
inspect.getsource(book) # where book is an Instance of the Book class.
```

The class stores the code blueprint, the instance is only a version of that blueprint with its own values. Hence, you need to pass the class.